# Updating Installation DeviceToken Manually

Tags: parse-platform

How can I change a deviceToken to ("undefined") manually? When I try to do it, the deviceToken is always reset automatically. What happened was I accidentally added the deviceToken manually and now I cannot remove it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange, I haven't encountered that message when updating the device token either in code or on the data browser. Can you provide some more details?

Comment: I had a bug in my code which would create two installations per user. One installation had the deviceToken, and the other had the _User pointer. What I did was manually copy the deviceToken, and paste it into the installation row that had a _User pointer associated with it(after spotting bug).                        However, I mistakenly pasted the wrong deviceToken (*face palm*). So, I tried to delete the incorrect deviceToken but it will not allow me. I remove it, but then after refreshing the page its back to the old deviceToken String. Thanks!

Comment: Makes sense -  It's always the simple things! glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: I still have not found the solution. I was saying 'thanks' in regards to your help with this question. Unfortunately, the old deviceToken String is still giving me trouble.

Comment: ahh I'm with you now! In that case, try typing  '(undefined)' (without the quotes) into the deviceToken field in data browser, that should work!

Comment: That is what I was trying at first, sorry, I should have made that more clear from the beginning.(undefined) did not work for me either.

Comment: hm - is there any reason you can't just delete that row and re-install your app in that case? If the original bug is now fixed so it won't happen again?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up just deleting the row as you mentioned.